# Add default telephone field in customer registration form in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to add default telephone field in our website Create and Account form, but I can not solve it.

Link for Form : http://gmr.goecommercebaby.com/customer/account/create/

### Solution

I have tried various code for this, after much searching I have used:

```
 <?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true)?>
```

and do some customization in "app/design/default/your_theme/template/persistent/cusomer/form/register.phtml" file.

If you want to use use this function then you get all address fields in registration form. After this, you can remove another fields and validation for unwanted fields.

Comment: I guess your question is more suitable at http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I have tried various code for this, after many searching i have used --

     <?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true)?>

and do some customization in "app/design/default/your_theme/template/persistent/cusomer/form/register.phtml" file.

If you want to use use this function then you get all address fields in registration form.
after this, you can remove another fields and validation for unwanted fields.

Comment: @KapilGupta Have you got the solution,i am in the same problem